# How to place a wordpress plugin (Custom Facebook Feed) inside a div?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I've been developing my first Wordpress theme and I am trying to place the "Custom Facebook Feed" plugin inside a `div` element in the `index.php` file.

The shorthand for including this plugin is `[custom-facebook-feed]`

This works if I enter it into a post via the wp-admin panel however if I try to use it directly in my index.php file it doesn't appear.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong (well obviously I am), I've read a bunch of pages regarding activation hooks and all sorts as I was unsure whether my theme was plugin enabled but can't seem to wrap my head around how plugins are implemented into the themes.

Here is the code from my index.php file

```
<?php get_header()?>

<!-- POSTS -->
<div class='col-sm-12 section'>
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post()?>

        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <?php the_content();?>

    <?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<!-- PLUGINS -->
<div class='col-sm-4 section'>
    <h1>Social</h1>
    <?php [custom-facebook-feed]?>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-4 section'>
    <h1>Instagram</h1>
    <p>
        Insert Instagram feed
    </p>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-4 section'>
    <h1>Music</h1>
    <p>
        Insert Soundcloud feed
    </p>
</div>

<?php get_footer()?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a post using this shorthand and then query that particular post and use a loop to display it inside that div?

Just an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use do_shortcode function:

```
<!-- PLUGINS -->
<div class='col-sm-4 section'>
    <h1>Social</h1>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[custom-facebook-feed]');?>
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: Thank you! Perfecto, I'm sure I was missing something so simple.

I managed to find a work around in the meantime by using the shortcode in a post, querying that particular post and using the `while(have_posts(): the_post();` to display it in the div but I'm pretty sure that is very very bad practise haha

Comment: @MunkyMead No problem. In wordpress plugins are useually designed to be used by non technical users, so they are activated either by shortcodes, or by using them as widgets. As a theme developer, you can use the function above to hardcode it, or (if you where distributing the theme to people) create a widget area in your theme at that location - http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was looking for this for an hour or so. Thank you. :)